# Elements of an arraylist as replacement in a files line

Tags: java, parsing, replace, java.util.scanner

I have this part of the code which reads a file linebyline. This original line that is about to be edited is:
j(ac)      "test"   /Aaa,Bbb/

I have an arraylist with elements [Ccc,Ddd,Eee] and I want these elements to be replaces in the line above between / and /.
The replcement between / and / works fine. However I cant put the arraylist straight to the .replace cause [] will also appear. So I am tryin to add the elements of the list. However I cant get the desired result which is: j(ac)      "test"   /Ccc,Ddd,Eee/

I keep getting only the first element: j(ac)      "test"   /Ccc/

How could I fix this?

```
List<String> strlist = new ArrayList<String>() ;

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

 while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
               String line = scanner.nextLine();

               if (line.contains("j(ac)")) {   

                   String skat ;
                   skat = null ;

                   for(String s : strlist) {
                   for (int index = 0; index < strlist.size(); index++) {

                               s = strlist.get(index);
                       skat=s;
                   }
                   }
                  String next = line.replaceAll("/.*?/", "/"+skat+"/");

                   System.out.print(next);


               }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close.

You just need to change,

`skat=s;` to `skat = skat + "," + s;`

this way you'll append to your list, add your commas, and not reset skat every iteration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This way it prints the desired result,but twice plus with null in front                                 /null,Ccc,Ddd,Eee,Ccc,Ddd,Eee/

Comment: seems like it's the result of the first for loop that loops over strtogams whatever strtogams is

Comment: what's inside `strtogams` and `strlist` ? I think there's a problem with what's inside `strtogams`.

Comment: sorry its the same. strtogams should be strlist. Irrelevant though with the results shown. Inside strlist there is what I wrote above [Ccc,Ddd,Eee]

Comment: Yes removed the first for (String s: strlist) and it now shows the right result once. But it sill have null in front of it. Probably its the initialization of skat at the beginning. skat = null. But how can i change that?

Comment: Changed the initialization to skat = "" and no null appears but I still get a plain unecessary , in front of the elements. How could i remove this?

Comment: Maybe i could do a new string.replaceAll. What should I put as regex to remove the first , only

Answer (score 0):

where you have skat=s, it needs to be skat+=s so it appends to skat as opposed to replacing it with a new string every iteration of the loop